# React Errors Gone Wrong

Tags: npm

[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\pc\OneDrive\Documents\youtube\eshop-tutorial\frontend\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\pc\OneDrive\Documents\youtube\Eshop-tutorial\frontend\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

npm start, was expecting it run well in my front end